# How to get end of month date from a "YearMonth" varchar column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

We have YearMonth VARCHAR(10) column and I am trying to create a date column which will give me last date of the month based on the YearMonth column.

```
For Example:
201612 - 12/31/2016
201602 - 02/29/2016
201702 - 02/28/2017
```

Comment: What sql have you tried? we need to see some effort :)

Answer (score 2):

Assume your varchar is 201612

```
Select EOMonth(cast(YourVarchar+'01' as date))
```

Returns

```
2016-12-31
```

If you wanted the MM/DD/YYYY format

```
Select Convert(varchar(10),EOMonth(cast(YourVarchar+'01' as date)),101)
```

Comment: @Justin Never had a doubt  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of SQL before 2012:

Add a month to the date with DATEADD, then subtract a day also with DATEADD

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '201612' + '01')))
```